# HTML allow user to type or paste in file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I allow a user to just type or paste in the file that they want?

[image: No file selected]

By clicking Choose File above I must use the file selector that pops up. How can I make it so I can just type in `test.png`?

[image]

Comment: You can't do it. That is browser implementation that you can not control. Years and years ago, you could. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is you can't.

This is a security measure. You are not allowed to browse the client's local file directory and find a file - they have to provide it for you. This even includes the user pasting the entire file path. You won't be able to make any meaning of it in JS - the file has to come through the native file browser or a drag-and-drop operation.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to make it so they can paste in a link to something? Say an image on the web? Or do I need a separate element for that?

Comment: You can't do that with the file input, you could do it with a regular `<input type="text">` element